# Open external link in iframe using drop down menu

Tags: php, iframe, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, external

I am using php to read a text file and generate a dropdown menu that will open a link in a new tab when an option is selected

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
<?php
if ($file = @fopen('data-receive.txt', 'r')) {
while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
echo "<option style='width:100px;' value='http://{$line}'>{$line}</option>";
}
fclose($file);
}
?>
</select>
```

This works perfectly and opens the selected website in a new tab.

However, I have an Iframe on the page and would like the drop down menu option to open in the iframe instead of a new tab

```
<iframe src="demo.html" name="test-frame" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Is this possible?
Any help would be much appreciated or [sms](http://xboxpcpro.co.uk/free-sms/) me

** SOLVED ** 
I changed

```
window.href.location
```

to

```
frames['test-frame'].location.href
```

Source:
http://konus.biz/books/DHTML/%D3%F7%E5%E1%ED%E8%EA%20JS%20%EE%F2%20quirksmode/iframe.html#

Comment: Use  JavaScript or jQuery to change the iframe src

Comment: lol, you could give him an example in the answer section.. i could give him one there too, but now im the bad guy cause you mentioned it in teh comment.  what gives? waiting for his response?

Comment: Thank you for responding I have now found the solution. I used : frames['test-frame'].location.href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="changeIframe">
<?php
if ($file = @fopen('data-receive.txt', 'r')) {
while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
echo "<option style='width:100px;' value='http://{$line}'>{$line}</option>";
}
fclose($file);
}
?>
</select>
```

**Ifarme:**

```
<iframe id="sourceIframe" src="demo.html" name="test-frame" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("sourceIframe");
var changeIframe= document.getElementById("changeIframe");

changeIframe.onchange = function()
{
    iframe.src = this.value;
}
```